# How to fetch inner array data from this array of objects

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

[Data from the server side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqKI0.png)

I need to fetch only tax array from this array of objects. How is it possible ? How can i write controller & model .

`$http.post("/ci/index.php/invoiceCtrl/addInvoice", $scope.invoice).then(function (response).{});`

Comment: If you are using angulajs, it might respond json object in which you can pick in codeigniter like `foreach( $jsonObject->tax as $taxes)`

Comment: in controller ??

Comment: in php use array_column function.

Comment: show us code how this receives to the controller

Comment: Inside a function like $scope.save =function(){}

Comment: $http.post("/ci/index.php/invoiceCtrl/addInvoice", $scope.invoice)
 .then(function (response)

Comment: Im passing all the values in $scope.invoice -as my object

Comment: **add code in question not in comments**

Comment: please format your code. its not that hard...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using angularjs and want to take the taxes array from your response object

```
$http.post("/ci/index.php/invoiceCtrl/addInvoice", $scope.invoice).then(onSuccess,onError);

function onSuccess(response){
  $scope.tax = JSON.parse(response).tax;
 //do whatever you want afterwards
}
function onError(error){
//error callback
}
```

Comment: not working..Tax is an array..unable to fetch that tax array

Comment: Try this.
var p = { myArray : response}

then
$scope.tax = p.myArray.tax

Comment: or when you are sending response from php application just use json_encode() on the response object